# Drop Spinner onFocus with xml code

Tags: android, xml, drop-down-menu, spinner, onfocus

I want to show the options on my spinner when that spinner get the focus.
The problem is the focus jump to other textview, ignoring the spinner.

This is the xml code:

```
        <LinearLayout>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lbTratamento"
                android:text="@string/lbTratamento"
                style="@style/label_padrao" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtTratamento"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                style="@style/txt_padrao"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/spnTipo" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lbTipo"
                 android:text="@string/lbTipo"
                style="@style/label_padrao" />
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnTipo"
                style="@style/spinner_padrao" 
                android:layout_width="150dp"   />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lbPalavraChave"
                 android:text="@string/lbPalavraChave"
                style="@style/label_padrao" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtPalavraChave"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                style="@style/txt_padrao" 
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/spnSexo"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lbSexo"
                 android:text="@string/lbSexo"
                style="@style/label_padrao" />
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnSexo"
                style="@style/spinner_padrao" 
                android:layout_width="150dp" 
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />  
        </LinearLayout>
```

Is it possible to do that with xml properties?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

inside the event OnCreate, write :

```
Spinner spnSexo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnSexo);
final String[] sexos = new String[]{"Male", "Female"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adSexo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, sexos);
adSexo.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spnSexo.setAdapter(adSexo);
```

Have Fun...

Answer (score 0):

I really can't tell what you want to do, based on this file.

I have some comments:

- Avoid setting layout widths in units. You'll only get into trouble. Let the system set
  the width. You should be using wrap_content if at all possible.
- There's no need to set focusable or focusableInTouchMode on a Spinner.
- Remove the nextFocusDown attributes to see if your problem is fixed.
- This file just tells me that you have two layouts on your window, containing a mix of
  labels, text entry fields, and spinners. It looks like it should work. What are you
  expecting it to do?

Comment: I just want show the list on the spinner after change the focus through the keyboard